# How to get attribute of item from a jQuery library

Tags: jquery

I am using this jQuery library:
http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

my html looks like this:

```
<div class="fileuploader" data-id="153777230352"></div>
```

the jQuery init library code looks like this.

```
$(".fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url: "upload.php",
    fileName: "myfile",
    onSuccess: function(files, data, xhr, pd) {
        var near = $(this).attr('data-id');
    }
});
```

I am trying to get the data-id value from inside the success trigger.

I had thought that `$(this)` would have got it, but I cant seem to figure out what the context of `this` is.

I cant simply use the class name to find it as there may be multiple instances on the page.

Is there a way of getting the data-id like this?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log($(this))` to see what it actually is?

Comment: Yes, it returns an object of data from the plug in.  Like "beforesend" , after send , cross domain  etc

Comment: I think easiest solution would be to send the element id to php and send that id back so you can retrieve it from your data object.

Comment: Are you sure this supports multiple instances? I'm not sure it does - I can't find anything in the docs to say it does, and trying it in JSFiddle, it just renders the last instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `this` within the `onSuccess` handler is not a reference to the element on which the `uploadFile()` function was called. It's a reference to the parent settings object.

To retain a reference to the element you're calling the library on you can instead use `each()` explicitly, like this:

```js
$(".fileuploader").each(function() {
  var $uploader = $(this);
  $uploader.uploadFile({
    url: "upload.php",
    fileName: "myfile",
    onSuccess: function(files, data, xhr, pd) {
      var near = $uploader.data('id');
      // work with 'near' here...
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

You can get HTML attribute of a item from a jQuery.

```
var near = $(this).data('id');
console.log(near);
```

Comment: His is saying in his question that his context of `this` is not the object he wants.